# How to continuously view images in FastStone Image Viewer?

Tags: images, photos, viewer, image-viewer

I'd like to have a possibility to continuously view images in **FastStone Image Viewer**.
Be able to choose a top level folder as a "root" and see all images in all subfolders in "flat cut".
The same concept is realized in **Google Picasa** and **Sony PlayMemories**.
Can it be done in **FastStone Image Viewer**?
Is there any way to write a plugin for it?

Comment: hi is not your question but you can see all subfolders using the slideshow from the toolbar